# Does a "tenfold increase" mean multiplying something by 10 or by 11?

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

If you have 10 cookies, and your number of cookies increases tenfold, you have 100 cookies, right? That's what I thought at first, but I recalled that if your number of cookies increases 200%, you get N + (200%/100%)N cookies where N was your original number of cookies, so you end up with 30 cookies, not 20. Shouldn't a tenfold (or threefold, or fourfold, or whatever) increase work the same way as a percentage increase?

For what it's worth, I'm interested in whether I should describe an increase from 0.8% to 3.4% as a "fourfold increase" or "threefold increase" (since 3.4%/0.8% = 4.25) in a scientific paper.

(I'm not sure whether this question belongs here or on math.SE.)

Comment: Since it's the *increase* and not the *total* that you're describing with *ten-fold*, 10x sounds right.

Comment: Answered at [Why is "a 100% increase" the same amount as "a two-fold increase"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91263/why-is-a-100-increase-the-same-amount-as-a-two-fold-increase). in general English, terminology hereabouts can lack clarity. In science, '[linear] scale factor 4.25' is surely required for both clarity and accuracy.

Comment: If it was *increased **by** tenfold*, you might have an argument for multiplying by 11 (although what you problem have is bad grammar). But *increased tenfold* means multiplying by 10.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid this terminology, especially in a scientific paper. The intended audience is even more likely than the average lay person to challenge whichever meaning of *x-fold increase* you happen to settle on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're interpreting "increase" to mean mathematical **addition**. But it can also simply mean "growing in size".

---

> The number of cookies increased tenfold.

This may be less ambiguous if you use "grew":

> The number of cookies grew tenfold.

This means that the number of cookies has grown **from** its original number **to** the tenfold of the original number.

---

If you want to talk about multiplying it by eleven, you could say something like

> The number of cookies **increased by** its tenfold.

When you say "increased by", you are talking about mathematical addition. The tenfold is **added to** the original number.

---

**edit**

I've been rightly corrected that tenfold cannot be used as a noun. Googling it, [it seems that **decuple**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decuple) is the correct noun. Never heard of it before, and I wouldn't know what it means just by hearing the word (it sounds much too close to "decouple").

Comment: I don't think you'd say "**its** tenfold." *Tenfold* is an adjective or adverb, not a noun. Even "increased by tenfold" is doubtful.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: You're right. [Decuple](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decuple) is the correct word according to dictionary.com (never heard of it tbh)