# Does a "two-fold decrease" result in a 'quantity - 200%' or a 'quantity/2'?

Tags: meaning

If I say that something had a "two-fold decrease", does it mean it was halved or that it was reduced by 200% (which can bring the value to a negative)?

Comment: 'Twofold' means to double. It does not mean ' to half' and it does not mean 'to reduce to zero'.https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/twofold

Comment: In order to say 'twofold decrease' you have to first state what the 'decrease' is. The you can double the decrease.

Comment: if I say about a "twofold increase" it is usually not necessary to specify the increase. I'm not understanding, sorry.

Comment: If I have ten things, and I have a twofold increase - then I have ten times two. Ten is already stated.But you have not stated what your decrease is, that you may double the decrease.

Comment: Is the following sentence meaningful? -  
"Initial ten things have decreased twofold"

Comment: It's meaningless to me, I'm afraid. 'Twofold' means double. You have to state a number before I know what doubling does to it.

Comment: I find some [scientific articles](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22twofold+decrease%22&btnG=) with usage of this phrase - which does not make it valid english, but indicates that it's used.

Comment: Plainly put, no (rational) native English speaker would use "twofold decrease".  Rather they'd say "cut in half" or some other more meaningful term.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/91263/17956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scientific papers mentioned in comment, the researchers have already established a *normal level* or a *level of x in healthy subjects.* Let us say it is ten per cent of something or other.

A fivefold increase would then be an increase up to fifty per cent of x.

A 'fivefold decrease' is their way of saying a fifth. They mean a reduction from, say 10% to 2%.

> Patients with anorexia nervosa had a fivefold ***decrease*** in subcutaneous fat and only a twofold decrease in intraabdominal fat **compared with the values for the volunteers**. Patients with Cushing syndrome had less than a twofold ***increase*** in subcutaneous fat and greater than a fivefold increase in intraabdominal fat **compared with values for the healthy subjects.**

[Body Fat Distribution](http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/abs/10.1148/radiology.170.2.2911678)

It is not, really, what a fivefold decrease means.

They are extrapolating back - it seems to me. If something drops from 10% to 2%, it would need a fivefold increase to get it back to where it was. So they are calling it a fivefold decrease, initially.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right about the extrapolation. The takeaway is that it's apparently not a correct English usage.