# What is the best way to say "A is 4 times as large as B"?

Tags: expressions

In my paper I will use the phrase "A is 4 times as large as B" very often. I find this tedious. Is there some more elegant way to express the idea?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You seem to be asking for writing advice, and "best" is rather subjective, so this question may be put on hold, so I might ask this: if it is tedious, why is it necessary to repeat so often? Is it not enough to have "B is one fourth as big as A" or "B is one quarter the size of A" or "A is quadruple the size of B"?

Comment: Somewhat related: [x times as many as or x times more than](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/187718#187718).

Comment: @choster I am sorry but I have many experiments and I have to give statements like "A is 4 times as large as B", "A is 5 times as large as B" and etc. "A is quadruple the size of B" will be a better choice. Thank you.

Comment: @choster That's terrible. Even if I could say "A is quadruple the size of B" instead of the tedious sentence "A is 4 times as large as B", what should I say for "A is 8 times as large as B", "A is 16 times as large as B", etc?

Comment: Then please edit your question. In your question you say you will use the **phrase** "*4 times as large*" choster was responding to that request. Give more than one example so that users cannot misinterpret your question. Note also that the title is *very* specific and restrictive.

Comment: Rolled back edit as it merely repeated the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is 24, and B is 6, then

A is 4 times greater than B.

A is 4 times the size of B.

A is the product of 4 and B.
(24 is the product of 4 and 6.)

A is 4 times B.
(24 is 4 times 6.)

A is 4 multiplied by B.
(24 is 4 multipled by 6.)