# When to use "than" and "of" in comparative sentences

Tags: word-usage

> The self-storage industry has three times the footprint than McDonald’s.

Or:

> The self-storage industry has three times the footprint of McDonald’s.

Comment: *The [footprint of the] self-storage industry is three times bigger than McDonald’s.* OR *The self-storage industry has three times the footprint of McDonald’s.* But NOT **The self-storage industry has three times the footprint than McDonald’s.*

Comment: Three times bigger is four times as big.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: I disagree. I've got 3 acres of land. You have one. Mine is three times bigger, right? How is it four times as big? (Or would you say it's 3 times as big and 2 times bigger?)

Comment: Believe what you wish to believe. But don't expect to pass math class.

Comment: Also relevant (at least to the discussion in the comments): ["X times as many as" or "X times more than"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than/187718#187718)

Answer (score 0):

The first needs a fix:

*The self-storage industry has **three times more** footprint **than** McDonald’s.*

The other is correct and - as Professor Lawler says - simpler.

Comment: _Three times the footprint of `Z`_ is OK, and quite common. Using _three times more_ just raises the question of whether you're talking about 3X or 4X, plus it requires comparative syntax, which is very fussy.

Comment: @JohnLawler Professor Lawler, surely I don't have anything against _Three times the footprint of Z_, just wanted to fix the other choice for the OP, so he/she would have more choices to choose from :-)

Comment: I have something against _three times more_ —exactly what Prof Lawler has against it—it's ambiguous at best, and misleading to anyone who takes it literally.

Comment: ... which leaves me wondering just how much of a lady Lionel Richie's woman was!