# Alternative for "as high as" for an academic text

Tags: single-word-requests, academia

I am writing a scientific paper that was sent to a language revision (proofreading) service. Unfortunately, the whole process runs via a web portal so that it is not possible for me the reply to the proofreader. For the sentence (simplified version)

> A is ten times *as high as* B.

a revision was suggested:

> A is ten times *higher than* B.

However in my opinion, the first sentence means `A = 10 x B`, whereas the second sentence means `A = 10 x B + B` (or `A - B = 10 x B`). Thus, the correct version would be:

> A is **nine** times *higher than* B.

## Questions

- Is *as high as* appropriate for academic texts?
- If not, what is an alternative?
- (Am I wrong with my opinion described above?), edit: answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187718/166633)

## Context

The sentence is from a paper on air pollution. `A` and `B` refer to concentrations of air pollutants at two distinct locations.

Comment: With all due respect, yours is a basic English question. They BOTH mean: A= 10 x B. Both can be said. Two ways to say the same thing. Dunno where the nine comes in at all. The first way is better in  your paper.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Why are you using the word "high" at all? If they're numbers/figures, it seems to me you could just say "A is ten times B".

Comment: I have no idea why your editor objects to the first; it's unambiguous and grammatically correct. The second is ambiguous, as noted in the question @EdwinAshworth links to. There's nothing wrong with saying "as high as" in academic writing.

Comment: Are you really talking about height or do you really mean ***larger***?

Comment: @Lambie : `A = 10 x B` (first sentence, 10 times as high) => `A = 9 x B + B` <=> `A - B = 9 x B` (third sentence, 9 times higher). To clarify the latter: I want to buy new boots. Their prize in shop `a` is 100 EUR (=A) and in shop `b` is 10 EUR (=B). *In shop a they cost 90 EUR more than in shop b.* <=> *In shop a the prize is 9 times the prize in shop b.*. If we were writing 10 times it was 100 EUR difference, which is wrong.

Comment: @sumelic : thanks for the comment; context added; should have included it before

Comment: @daniel.neuman If A = 10 X B, it cannot be: A = 9 x B + B, it's either one or other. And my non-math brain tells me they both mean the same thing in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The editor is right to object to your phrase, or at least, I wouldn't use it in formal writing either. It might depend on the field but it just doesn't feel "right" to me. I don't, however, agree with the suggested alternative. I would instead suggest you write:

> A is ten times the height of B.

That clearly and unambiguously means that the `height(A) = 10 x height(B)`. You haven't given any context here, but depending on what you want to say and what A and B are, you might also want to consider:

> A is ten times B.
>
> A is greater than B by a factor of 10.

Comment: For parallelism, I would prefer "The height of A is ten times the height of B" (which I suppose could be reduced to "The height of A is ten times that of B"). Otherewise I agree with this.

Comment: @sumelic interesting. For some reason I don't much like *The height of A is ten times the height of B* (though I do prefer your shorter version). I admit that I am imagining this in the context of bar graphs where A and B are bars.

Answer (score 2):

Both *A is ten times as high as B* and *A is ten times higher than B* can be used. Although one may think that the latter means *A is eleven times as high as B*, it really means the same as the former.

I imagine that here A and B are walls with different heights, in which case you can write *A's height is ten times B's* to make things crystal clear. If they are numbers, you should just use *A is ten times B*.