# “Have twice the” question

Tags: grammar

This is how I say it:

“You have twice the experience I have”

to me it feels right, but searching examples on the net, I don’t quite find a similar example. I could rephrase. I think these are safe:

“You have twice more experience than I have”
or
“You have twice as much experience as I do”

but back to my original way of saying it, is there something missing before “I have”?

“You have twice the experience that I have”

It sounds better without the “that” to me.

Comment: Stay away from "twice more"   Your "twice the" and "twice as much" are both fine.   You could insert a "that" or you can elide it as you have done:  "twice the experience that I have."

Comment: Related: [“X times as many as” or “X times more than”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7894/216106)

Answer (score 3):

Twice means 2x. Twice more means thrice or 3x.

To say that someone has two times the experience you do, as @Jim commented, it's most common to use:

> You have twice the experience I have.

There are other ways, but people often misunderstand percentages, so the simplest method is recommended.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought about "twice more" as "as much plus twice as much". I wonder do other people agree this definition?

Comment: oh haha I see what you mean now. Twice plus the existing is thrice :D Thank you

Comment: @RustyCore It's simple to me, but that doesn't mean others understand it. Five more means my amount plus another five. Twice more means my amount plus another two times that amount - or a total of three times the initial amount. If I have 10, twice that is 20; 10 plus twice more is 10 + 20, or 30.

Answer (score 3):

You're saying it fine.

*Twice* is one of several adverbs that can be followed by a noun phrase describing a quantity to further modify that quantity. (With rephrasing, you could use numbers too!) The Oxford English Dictionary explains this form in 2a. for "twice, adv. (n. and adj.)":

> a. with a numeral, or a noun or noun phrase expressing quantity: Two times as much as; double of.

Compare several alternative insertions where the syntax is otherwise unchanged:

> You have double the experience I have.
>
> You have half the experience I have.
>
> You have ten times the experience I have.

And consider similar insertions for the object following it.

> You have twice the ketchup I have.
>
> You have twice the money I have.
>
> You have twice the number of fans I have.